# How to do inner joining in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, join, nosql

Is it possible to do SQL inner joins kind of stuff in MongoDB?

I know there is the `$lookup` attribute in an aggregation pipeline and it is equivalent to **outer joins** in SQL, but I want to do something similar to **inner joins**.

I have three collections which  need to merge together:

```javascript
// User Collection
db.User.find({});

// Output:
{
   ID : 1,
   USER_NAME : "John",
   password : "pass"
}
{

   ID : 2,
   USER_NAME : "Andrew",
   PASSWORD : "andrew"
}

// Role Collection
db.ROLE.find({});

// Output:
{
   ID : 1,
   ROLE_NAME : "admin"
},
{
    ID : 2,
    ROLE_NAME : "staff"
}

// USER_ROLE Collection
db.USER_ROLE.find({});

// Output:
{
   ID : 1,
   USER_ID : 1,
   ROLE_ID : 1
}
```

I have the above collections and I want to extract only the documents matched with users and their respective roles, not all the documents. How can I manage it in MongoDB?

Comment: If inner joins are critical, consider embedding data. Otherwise, you have to run multiple queries to join multiple collections exactly the way you want.

Comment: convert any query to mongo query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155715/how-do-i-write-this-sql-query-in-mongodb-syntax

Comment: MongoDB sucks for lack of inner join. If it's supposed to handle large amounts of data, then a M:N relationship is pretty common. Even though you can embedded data, it's not ideal if you have a single M:N relationship which you will in most projects. SQL is only a good choice because of this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Tiramisu wrote this looks like schema issue.

You can make a manual inner join, by removing documents where $lookup returned empty array.

```
....
{$lookup... as myArray},
{$match: {"myArray":{$ne:[]}}},
{$lookup... as myArray2},
{$match: {"myArray2":{$ne:[]}}},
```

> schema change

I personally will go for schema update, like this:

```
db.User.find({})
{
   ID : 1,
   USER_NAME : "John",
   password : "pass"
   roles:[{ID : 1,  ROLE_NAME : "admin"}]
}


db.ROLE.find({})
{
   ID : 1,
   ROLE_NAME : "admin"
},
```

Comment: thanks for the answer profesor79 but is it a good way to map embed way isn't that cause data redundancy assume if many users has same role then same role will repeatedly added in all the documents thats the problem i having

Comment: If you are worried about data redundancy go for relational DB. NoSql approach favors denormalised data.

Answer (score 28):

I found answer my self it was

> $unwind
>   done the trick to me following query worked for me

```
    db.USER.aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "USER_ROLE",
                localField: "ID",
                foreignField: "USER_ID",
                as: "userRole"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$userRole",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "ROLE",
                localField: "userRole.ROLE_ID",
                foreignField: "ID",
                as: "role"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$role",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                "role.ROLE_NAME": "staff"
            }, {
                $project: {
                    USER_NAME: 1,
                    _id: 0
                }
            }
            ]).pretty()
```

Anyway thanks for the answers

Comment: Is there any difference between this and `$match: { $ne }` method? Which one is more "idiomatic"?

Answer (score 2):

Will this help

```
const RolesSchema = new Schema({
  ....

});
const Roles = mongoose.model('Roles', RolesSchema);


const UserSchema = new Schema({
  ...

  roles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Roles" }]
});
```

using the [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) on userschema you can also reduce the redundancy

Answer (score 2):

Well you are correct, `$lookup` attribute is equivalent to outer joins in SQL, but in mongoDB, you need additional aggregation stages so as to perform a similar `INNER JOIN` in mongo. Here's an example for joining `User` and `ROLE` collections based on the `ID` and displaying the results based on `USER_NAME` and `ROLE_NAME`

```
    db.User.aggregate([{
      $lookup: {
          from: "ROLE",
          localField: "ID",
          foreignField: "ID",
          as: "result"
        }
    },{
       $match: {
           result: {
             $ne: []
           }
        }
    },{
      $addFields: {
           result: {
             $arrayElemAt: ["$result",0]
           }
      }
    },{
       $project: {
          USER_NAME: "$USER_NAME",
          ROLE_NAME: "$result.ROLE_NAME"
       }
    }])
```

**Hope it helps!!**

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB **$lookup** aggregation is the most formal and the best-optimized method for this question. However, If you are using **Node.js** as the server-side, Then you can use a little hack as follows.

```
CollectionOne.find().then((data0) => {
    if (data0.length > 0) {
        let array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data0.length; i++) {
            let x = data0[i]
            let y = x.yourForeignKey;
            array.push({_id: y});
        }
        CollectionTwo.find(
            {$or: array}
        ).then((data1) => {
            res.status(200).json(data1);
        }).catch((error1) => {
            return error1;
        })
    }
}).catch((error0) => {
    return error0;
});
```

I used the Array `Push()` method and the `$or` operator of MongoDB. You can use the `$nor` operator instead of the `$or` to find outer join documents. And also you can change the finding algorithm by using `$ne`, `$nor`, `$or`, `$and` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

**$lookup aggregation** 
Performs a left outer join to a collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. The
$lookup
stage adds a new array field to each input document. The new array field contains the matching documents from the "joined" collection. The
$lookup
stage passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.

Starting in MongoDB 5.1,
$lookup
works across sharded collections.

To combine elements from two different collections, use the
$unionWith
pipeline stage.

**Syntax** 
The $lookup stage has the following syntaxes:

**Equality Match with a Single Join Condition** 
To perform an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the "joined" collection, the
$lookup
stage has this syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

More details: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do using lookup. Check out syntaxfactory.io for example code. Select mongodb and search.It will show examples for all types of joins you can do in mongodb

Answer (score -5):

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.002GB
> use local
switched to db local
> show collections
startup_log
test1
test2
> db.test2.aggregate([{
...    $lookup: {
...       from: "test1",
...       localField: "id",
...       foreignField: "id",
...       as: "aggTest"
...    }
... }])
```

Comment: This doesn't provide any useful information